# Understanding $Bl_{\mathcal{I}}(k^4)/S_2$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is defined by $(x_1-x_2,x_3-x_4)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, projective-schemes, graded-modules

Let $k_4=Spec(k[x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4])$ and $\mathcal{I}$ is the ideal sheaf defined by $(x_1-x_2,x_3-x_4)$. Then

$$
Bl_{\mathcal{I}}(k^4) = Proj (\oplus_{i\geq 0} I^i t^i) 
$$
where $I=(x_1-x_2,x_3-x_4)$.

> Then considering $Bl_{\mathcal{I}}(k^4)/S_2$ where $S_2$ is the symmetric group on $2$ letters, how do we write or see 
>   $$
> Bl_{\mathcal{I}}(k^4)/S_2
> $$
>   as $Proj$? The $S_2$ action on $Bl_{\mathcal{I}}(k^4)$ is by interchanging $(x_1,x_3)\in k^2$ with $(x_2, x_4)\in k^2$?

$$
$$